# How to load array of images in haskell(gloss)?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, gloss

I am very new to Haskell and do not have good understanding of monads for now. I am using gloss for making chess. The issue I am facing is in the loading of multiple images. I am using `loadBMP` function provided by haskell to load image. Its signature is:

```
loadBMP :: FilePath -> IO Picture
```

I can load single image but can't load array of images.

```
-- This function calculates the path of all the images and then apply loadBMP function on it.

loadPieceImages :: [IO Picture]
loadPieceImages = do
  map (loadBMP . (\n -> "images/" ++ n ++ ".bmp") . (\n -> if n < 6 then show n ++ "-w" else show (n `mod` 6) ++ "-b")) [0 .. 12]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  images <- loadPieceImages  -- On this line I am getting error.
  play window (makeColor 1 0 0 1) 30 initialState draw transform (const id)
```

The main issue is that I have `[IO Picture]` type but I don't how will be turn it into `[Picture]`.

This thing might be very basic but I can't understand monads for now. So kindly explain the answer you give.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've (correctly) declared `main` as `IO ()`, the `do` notation and the `<-` arrow enables you to 'peel off' the `IO` wrapper. Thus, when you write `images <- loadPieceImages`, the compiler expects `loadPieceImages` to have an `IO` type. `loadPieceImages`, however, has the type `[IO Picture]`, which is why the compiler complains. The outermost wrapper is `[]`, not `IO`.

If, on the other hand, you had a `IO [Picture]` value, you'd be able to use the `<-` arrow to peel of the `IO` wrapper to 'get at' the `[Picture]` list inside it.

In other words, you need a function with the type `[IO Picture] -> IO [Picture]`. You can [Hoogle that type](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%5BIO%20Picture%5D%20-%3E%20IO%20%5BPicture%5D) and consider the suggestions.

Once you get the hang of it, you'll start to notice that whenever you want to 'flip' the 'stacking' of two wrappers (like `IO` and `[]`), there's a general-purpose function for that: [sequence](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/GHC-Base.html#v:sequence). This function takes a list of any `Monad m` and flips it to `m [a]`. Since `IO` is a `Monad` instance, that'll work here as well.

So, something like

```
images <- sequence loadPieceImages
```

should work (I haven't actually tried to compile this, since the OP isn't a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so it's possible you'll have to tweak this a bit, but that's the general idea: use `sequence`).

Comment: I'd say probably the right fix is rather to change the `map` in the definition of `loadPieceImages` to `mapM` (and fix the type signature accordingly).